# can't go on monitor mode in kali linux

Tags: wifi

I can't seem to make my interface go on monitor mode, here is my terminal
https://gyazo.com/c2a84f7585ea89e59e56bbe1ed585fc5

https://gyazo.com/2ba669ca7f62787b126e2e107beefb24

Answer (score 4):

Although that kill processes command `airmon-ng check kill` may solve the problem, **don't use it** because you'll **stop many functionalities** including the network-manager application.

Instead, use the following commands when starting monitor mode:

```
#> airmon-ng start wlan0
#> ifconfig wlan0mon down
#> iwconfig wlan0mon mode monitor
#> ifconfig wlan0mon up
```

Comment: wlan0mon: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Comment: iwconfig, and check its name, maybe wlan1mon, or just mon0.

Answer (score -1):

**Try as suggested on the terminal**

`sudo airmon-ng check kill`

and then try

`sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`